# Solution box in book class

Tags: exam, books, box

I am writing a book, 95% completed, and I intend to change an environment as soon as it is over. I wrote the entire book with the `exam` class, because when I started I had no idea that it is very different from the `book` class. Now I want to return to the `book` class and for that I need the `solutionbox` environment present in the `exam` class, but I can't find any solution that is similar to what the `exam` class provides. The other alternatives do not present the box, only the solution environment. Thanks for your help, below is a demonstration:

[image]